# Workaround for Firebase's "Rules Are Not Filters" constraint

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I’d like a security rule that lets anyone get a list of users and read their names, but only allows logged in users to view their own email.

Here’s an example data structure:

```
    "User" : {
        "abc123" : {
          "name" : "Bob",
          "email" : "bob@hotmail.com"
        }   
    }
```

A naive approach to a security rule might be to do the following:

```
"User" : {
    "$user" : {
        "name" : {
            ".read" : true
        },
        "email" : {
            ".read” : "auth.uid === $user"
        }
    }
}
```

However because there is no read rule at the User level, requests to read the list will be denied. But adding a read rule at the User level will override the email rule, and make every child node readable (see [Rules Cascade](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-cascade) in Firebase's Security Guide).

The Security guide does point out that [Rules Are Not Filters](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter), but doesn’t offer much guidance as to what to do about it.

Should I just split my User entity up into PrivateUser and PublicUser?

Comment: That is indeed one common way of doing this. In general when modeling data in NoSQL, model the data for how you intend to use it in your app. See this article for more good advice: https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/

Comment: Thanks Frank, I don't have any experience with NoSQL databases. My naive approach was to go, "Ok, I need a user object, and a user has these properties, some of which are private". So are you saying a better thought process would be to first think about access, and then to model objects that are either completely public or completely private?

Comment: It's very common for people coming from a SQL background to try and model their relational model into a hierarchical system (like Firebase). It just doesn't work. Read the article and you'll be better equipped to cope. Also recommended reads on the Firebase web site: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html, https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html. This seems good too: https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data and this recent post on our Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/1p4O4Pc2w6k

Answer (score 2):

To let anyone get a list of users and read their names. AND to allow logged in users to view their own email.

> **[Zac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/389379/zac) says:** first think about access, and then to model objects that are either completely public or completely private.

**Type 1:**

```
{"rules":{
  "user_publicly":{"$user:{
    ".read":true,
    "name":{}
  }},
  "user_privately":{"$user:{
    ".read":"auth != null && $user == auth.uid",
    "email":{}
  }}
}}
```

**Type 2:**

```
{"rules":{
  "user":{"$user:{
    "public":{
        ".read":true,
        "name":{}
    },
    "private":{
        ".read":"auth != null && $user == auth.uid",
        "email":{}
    }
  }}
}}
```

Comment: I agree, especially when modelling with NoSQL rules, always try to make a private & public access in your structure, its possibly more efficient than having to make another duplicate set of data somewhere outside the Users node all over again

Answer (score 1):

A "workaround" would be to use Firestore (has a lot of the good things from Firebase Realtime Database, but adds more querying options, etc).

**There is no "rules are not filters" restriction in Firestore!**
EDIT:
Thanks to @DougStevenson for making me be more specific.
In Firestore, rules are still not filters, but they are compatible with filtering, unlike in Firebase Realtime DB.

Though, you have to construct your query in such a way, as to only return objects for which you have read permission (otherwise you get a security exception).

Here are some starting point docs:

Security rules:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/

Queries: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: This is not true.  Security rules are still not filters in Firestore. The client has to filter based on the expectations of the rules.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters

Comment: @DougStevenson - true - they are not filters, but they are compatible with filtering. I'm adding an edit. Thanks.